# Take sum of last 7 days with datetime

Tags: python, date, sum

My data looks like this:

```
    Date        AcuteLegs_1day  
74  2021-12-09  450.0   
75  2021-12-10  840.0   
76  2021-12-13  900.0   
77  2021-12-14  630.0   
78  2021-12-15  400.0   
79  2021-12-16  360.0   
80  2021-12-19  150.0   
81  2021-12-20  600.0   
82  2021-12-21  600.0
```

I want a new column with the sum off this load off the last 7 days: Now I use:

```
df['AcuteLegs_7days']=df["AcuteLegs_1day"].rolling(7).sum()
df['AcuteLegs_7days']=df['AcuteLegs_7days'].shift(1)
```

This works nice. But it takes the sum from the last 7 rows. But because sometimes there is no data from a date the last seven rows is not the last 7 days.

What I want is if a date is missing, this will add 0 to the trainingload sum of 7 days.

Comment: Do you want to insert the missing dates, or just change the way you calculate the sum?

Comment: I dont want to add the missing data because there are way more columns with other features, in which I don't want to add more missing data. But I want the sum function to use the dates, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can resample to create the missing day and fill with 0 before doing sum.

```
df = df.resample('D').sum().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I dont want to add new rows because there are way more features and adding missing data in these columns would be bad